# Make p-dropdown options right aligned in primeng

Tags: angular, primeng

I have following html code which use PrimeNG p-Dropdown component. I want to align the options to be right aligned.(Left aligned by default). Is there a way to achieve this. I tried updating the style class but no luck with that either.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <p-dropdown inputId="state" formControlName="{{demos}}"
         [options]="demoOptions" [styleClass]="'prm-dropdown prm-filter-dropdown'" 
         [dropdownIcon]="'bx bxs-chevron-down'" placeholder="{{demoOptions}}" 
         (onChange)="onValueChange(demoOptionId)">
    </p-dropdown>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is very easy:

Demo: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-dynamicdialog-demo-zqgnqz?file=src/styles.css)

for primeng version 12

```
.p-dropdown-panel .p-dropdown-items .p-dropdown-item {
  text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: That did not work under Angular 8.  Also adding `style="text-align: left"` gave the error `Cannot find a differ supporting object 'text-align: left'`.  Primeng seems to be incompatible with normal use of styles.

Comment: NOTE: That only works if you do it at style.css, thus changing the appearance for ALL dropdowns in the application.